# How to replace single quotes with two single quotes in bash in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace single quotes in my string with double quotes using sed.

I have tried like this echo it's a lovely day | sed "s/'/\"/g" but the string finds no matches and gives no result.

I am using Bash on Ubuntu for windows

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use `sed`, consider `tr` instead... (eg. `tr \' \"`)

Comment: I realised my mistake, I wasn't surrounding the text with echo in " " marks.

Comment: The question's title says: `... with two single quotes` (e.g. `''`) the body of the question says: `with double quotes` e.g.(`"`)... - imho, thats different.

Comment: Properly answer: assuming `txt="I'm hungry"`, **replace one single quote with two single quotes** doing `txt2=${txt//\'/\'\'}` and **replace one single quote with one double quote** doing `txt2=${txt//\'/\"}`, and `echo $txt2` to see the result.

Answer (score 7):

An expansion can get you what you want very simply :

```
original="it's a lovely day"
modified=${original//\'/\"}
echo "$modified"
```

In addition to its simplicity, this expansion uses no external command (only shell features), so the performance overhead is much lower than launching a separate process.

Breaking the syntax down a bit :

- `${original...}` means we are expanding the `original` variable
- `//` means "search all occurrences"
- `\'` is an escaped single quote (the text to search for)
- The lone `/` means "replace by"
- `\"` is an escaped double quote (the text to replace by)

Another fun way to do it :

```
repl()
{
  local IFS="$2$1"
  set -- $3
  echo "$*"
}

repl \'  \"  "it's a lovely day"
repl "'" '"' "it's a lovely day" # Quoted rather than escaped
```

Can be made POSIX-compliant at the cost of a subshell (see comment below) :

```
repl()
(
  IFS="$2$1"
  set -- $3
  echo "$*"
)

(repl \'  \"  "it's a lovely day")
(repl "'" '"' "it's a lovely day") # Quoted rather than escaped
```

The subshell is created by enclosing the statements in parentheses.  Not doing this would change the value of IFS (which is not declared "local" as in the first version), which you very probably want to avoid.

Comment: I wanted to replace a `'` with `'\''` so when I use `eval "'$a'"`, any quotes in `$a` won't close my quoting. `eval "'${a//\'/'\''}'"` didn't work, but `$quot="'\''"; eval "'${a//\'/$quot}'"` did.